# i try to select data from multiple tables with four indexes

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables and i try to create a table for managing data.

the first table is "questions":

```
questions (question_id, key1, key2, key3, key4, user_id, creation_date, class, type     permission)
```

and the other:

```
questions_keys (question_key_id, question_key_name, question_key_refers_to)
```

every time i push the submit button stored in the table question_keys four records and one in table of questions. heres an example:

question_keys:

```
1, mathematics, 0
2, history, 1
3, physics, 2
4, geography, 3
```

and question table:

```
(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 2012-12-19 20:41:48, 4, multiple_choice,     0)
```

the query i need: in the table show the question_key_name where key1, key2, key3, key4 in table questions is equal to question_key_id.

and show in one row something like this:

`mathematics, history, physics, geography, multiple_choice, 2012-12-19 20:41:48`  etc

i'm new and i need your help.. thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure about what you need, the result is not really clear though... Could you explain a bit more please ?

Comment: is there any relationship between these two tables?

Comment: no.. imagine the question table with the difference in the four keys. will be replaced with question_key_name where key1-key4 is the same with question_key_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT qk1.question_key_name qk2.question_key_name, qk3.question_key_name, 
       qk4.question_key_name, q.type, q.creation_date 
FROM questions q 
INNER JOIN question_keys qk1 ON q.key1 = qk1.question_key_id 
INNER JOIN question_keys qk2 ON q.key2 = qk2.question_key_id 
INNER JOIN question_keys qk3 ON q.key3 = qk3.question_key_id 
INNER JOIN question_keys qk4 ON q.key4 = qk4.question_key_id;
```

Comment: explain me how should be the while? example: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData, MYSQL_ASSOC)){?>
    <tbody>
<?php

echo '<tr id="row_'.$row['question_id'].'">';
echo '<td align=center><input type="text" name="key1" id="key1_'.$row['question_id'].'" style="text-align: center" value="' . $row['key1'] . '" size=10/></td>';
echo '<td align=center><input type="text" name="key2" id="key2_'.$row['question_id'].'" style="text-align: center" value="' . $row['key2'] . '" size=12/></td>'; etc

Comment: I am not aware of PHP code. I am good at mysql so explain your issue in syntax of mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to join the tables four times with this design:

```
SELECT question_key_name
FROM question_key qk
JOIN questions q on q.key1 = qk.question_key_id
WHERE q.question_id = ?
```

and then repeat for the other 3.  You can UNION them all together, which would return you 4 rows.

As for returning only one row, check out GROUP_CONCAT, but that will return you the question_key_name values as one column.  You may be better off combining the 4 rows in your app code.